# NotSerializableException - is it because it is a Singleton class?

Tags: android, exception, serialization

I am getting NotSerializableException when trying to write out a class to a bundle.
It is defined as Serializable but was wondering if the fact that it is defined as a singleton could be causing problems.

Comment: If you post a snippet from your code along with the stack trace, it would be easier to answer this question.